# I'm getting ClassCastException even though I overriden compareTo()

Tags: java, classcastexception, comparator, compareto

I am getting ClassCastException error. This error occurs when I insert the object that is derived from a class I have created.
My code is below:
When I run, I always get ClassCastException error.
Also, the comparator of my class is shown as null in debugger.

I have written a comparator (as far as I know) and overridden necessary methods.

How can I use a Set<> with a class that I have created and use contains() method?

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>
{
    int age;
    double height;
    public Person(int age, double height)
    {
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person person) 
    {
        return age - person.age;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        final Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (this.age == other.age)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Set<Person> people = new HashSet<>();
        Person p1 = new Person(10, 1.00);
        Person p2 = new Person(11, 1.10);
        Person p3 = new Person(12, 1.20);
        Person p4 = new Person(14, 1.40);
        people.add(p1);
        people.add(p2);
        people.add(p3);
        people.add(p4);
        if(people.contains(12))
            System.out.println("contains");
        else
            System.out.println("does not contain");
    }
}
```

I have managed to get rid of the error. But now, the output is "does not contain".

Comment: You should change that `equals` implementation, otherwise you will have a bad time...

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the `ClassCastException`? And what is the error message?

Comment: I am getting ClassCastException when I try to call contains() method of a list with full of my objects "Adjacent".

Comment: So is the code above in the `Adjacent` class?  And what type is the field called `adjacent`?

Comment: adjacent is type of Sensor. Same with the one returns from getSensor() method.

Comment: Can you show us the declaration and instantiation of your list, and your call to `contains`?  Also, a stack trace would be nice.

Comment: I have written a similar code for you to understand better

Comment: OK, this is now a completely different question - but you've got a set of `Person`, and you're looking for an `int` inside.  An `int` is not a `Person`.

Comment: The problem is completely different from what was originally wrote. I think `people.contains(12)` should be changed to `people.contains(p3)`.

Comment: I want to search the list with respect to ages i.e. "is there a person who is 12 years old?" is there a way to do this?

Comment: you should try `people.contains(new Person(12, 1.20))` instead of `people.contains(12)`.

Comment: Creating a brand new object for a comparison is redundant. Moreover, what if the person is not 1.20?

Comment: You completely changed the nature of the question.  You should post another one (it's not a bad question). Long story short, you can't call `contains(int)` on a `HashSet<Person>`.  You really need to wrap it in a `Person`.  The contains will only check the identity fields so the "1.20" won't matter.  The identity fields are the ones you use for `equals` and `hashcode`.

Comment: Use completely changed the question and now answers are not matching up anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am about to suggest has nothing to do with ClassCastException, which is thrown simply because you are checking `contains` with an `int` argument on a set of objects of type `Person` ... short answer: you can't cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance. Even [the javadoc says exactly that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html).

For situations like this, I really like to use Guava predicates. A predicate allows you to apply a boolean condition to any iterable, returning those elements that satisfy the specified condition. In your example, you can define predicates that return the subset of people of whatever age you want.

```
Predicate<Person> getAgePredicate(final int age) {
    return new Predicate<Person>() {
        public boolean apply(Person p) { return p.age == age; }
    };
```

}

```
Set<Person> people = new Hashset<>();
... // populate people
Set<Person> peopleOfAgeTwelve = Sets.filter(people, getAgePredicate(12));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your class `Adjacent` implements `Comparable` interface based on your code. And your class contains a method called `getID()`. So therefore when you override the `compareTo()` method, you want to make sure that the object comparison makes sense. I'm not sure what your `getID()` returns. But it seems like integer. So you might want to change the implementation of `compareTo()` as follows:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Adjacent adj) {

    return this.getId() - adj.getId();
}
```

So this way the comparison will return negative/zero/positive depending on the ID comparison of two `Adjacent` class objects.

Also in your overrided `equals()` method, the implementation is incorrect because two objects are not necessarily equal even if they have the same hash code. A good example of overriding `equals` and `hashCode` methods is given in [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java). Also, in your case, I think you probably don't even need to override `equals` method since your class implements `Comparable` interface already.

Comment: None of that is going to help with the ClassCastException.

Comment: Without the actual code that throws the exception, I can't tell what the cause is. But those are the points I can see from the post where the problems might come from.

Comment: No, those issues won't cause ClassCastException.  The reason why Stack Overflow lets us post comments under a question is so that we can ask for the actual information we need _before_ we post an answer, not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call contains with a parameter that's a different type; this behavior is actually [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29). The `contains()` method is a non-generic method for legacy reasons, and it's not safe if you're using a `TreeSet`. If you implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` and switch to a `HashSet`, your problems will go away.

Do you really need people sorted by age?

Edit: I see what you're trying to do, now. You don't want a `Set`, you want `Map<Integer, Collection<Person>>`, or just a single pass loop to look for the given age.

```
for (Person p : people) {
    if (p.age == 12) ...;
}
```

or

```
Map<Integer, Set<Person> peopleByAge = new HashMap<Integer, Set<Person>>();
for (Person p : people) {
    if (!peopleByAge.contains(p.age)) {
        peopleByAge.put(p.age, new TreeSet<Person>();
    }
    peopleByAge.get(p.age).add(p);
}

if (people.age.containsKey(12)) ...
```

Comment: I don't need to sort the list. I just want to see that if there is a person with the age of 12.

Comment: Then run that for loop. If you're going to be doing it a lot, you'll want Map<Integer, Integer>.  If you need a list of everyone who's 12, you need the second example.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check.

Comment: A person age 12 isn't the same as the Integer 12.